# How can additional data be associated with existing objects using extension methods?

Tags: c#, methods, properties, attributes, extension-methods

Since .NET Framework 3.5, developers have been able to add extension methods callable from instances of any object type. Extension properties have not been implemented in C#, however. Unlike extension methods, extension properties would involve storing some extra state information for individual objects.

However, even for extension methods, it would be highly useful in some programming scenarios to be able to access after-added/extension information for the objects on which those extension methods are called.

Here is the original question:  **How can one add extension properties, or otherwise set extended data on an object in C#?**

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: "How can additional *data* be associated with existing objects?" is how I read it - I'm waiting for his self-answer; I know how to do with with RCW objects, but not in general.

Comment: Why would you want to do this? Aren't normal composition or inheritance good enough?

Comment: Not always, @svick. One can't always extend an existing class, yet may want to add extension methods to it. In addition using these ideas one can approximate the usefulness of extension properties. I've upvoted your comment, though.

Comment: You can add extension methods for structs and enums.

Comment: Extension methods are different, they add functionality, not state, which I think makes much more sense. Though it's true that attached properties are sometimes useful in WPF.

Comment: @Lee, fixed--the idea I was trying to express really is that this will work for object types but not structs or enums.

Comment: @svick, I don't have experience with WPF yet. I am just trying to free myself from the messiness of having to externally store and pass in to extension methods useful info. This sort of situation seems to crop up wherever there's some third-party API with lots of little internally generated objects which may need to be manipulated, but where the code to do so must endlessly call factory methods for the same old contextual objects, etc. If extra context could be attached to items, then calling code could still have direct access to them when helpful, but be freed from complexity.

Comment: I'm astounded that this was closed as "not a real question". It's not difficult to tell what's being asked--the question is clearly how to add properties or other extended data to an object at runtime. Not only is it a valid question, it has a real, valid answer that was indicated to be such by four people AFTER presumed downvotes.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The [System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConditionalWeakTable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd413870.aspx) class seems to be just what the doctor ordered, and doesn't seem to entail the sort of memory leak worries that other approaches might raise. Following is my first simple wrapper around the use of ConditionalWeakTable. I will hide them a bit better (make them internal and more obscurely named) and put other methods in front of them, but this works and is a big relief and help to me.

(Thanks to svick, Jeppe Stig Nielsen, Tormod, and user2246674 for helping me think this through.)

```
public static class ExtensionMethods
{
    private static System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConditionalWeakTable<object, object> extendedData = new System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConditionalWeakTable<object, object>();

    internal static IDictionary<string, object> CreateDictionary(object o) {
        return new Dictionary<string, object>();
    }

    public static void SetExtendedDataValue(this object o, string name, object value) {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(name)) throw new ArgumentException("Invalid name");
        name = name.Trim();

        IDictionary<string, object> values = (IDictionary<string, object>)extendedData.GetValue(o, ExtensionMethods.CreateDictionary);
//            if (values == null)
//                extendedData.Add(o, values = new Dictionary<string, object>()); // This doesn't seem to be necessary!

        if (value != null)                 
            values[name] = value;
        else
            values.Remove(name);
    }

    public static T GetExtendedDataValue<T>(this object o, string name)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(name)) throw new ArgumentException("Invalid name");
        name = name.Trim();

        IDictionary<string, object> values = (IDictionary<string, object>)extendedData.GetValue(o, ExtensionMethods.CreateDictionary);
//            if (values == null) // ... nor does this!
//                return default(T);
//            else 
        if (values.ContainsKey(name))
            return (T)values[name];
        else
            return default(T);
    }

    internal static object GetExtendedDataValue(this object o, string name)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(name)) throw new ArgumentException("Invalid name");
        name = name.Trim();

        IDictionary<string, object> values = (IDictionary<string, object>)extendedData.GetValue(o, null);
        if (values == null)
            return null;
        else if (values.ContainsKey(name))
            return values[name];
        else
            return null;
    }
}
```

(**EDIT**: The original answer follows, for historical purposes.)

The System.ComponentModel.TypeDescriptor.GetAttributes(object) method exposes a collection of System.Attribute objects that have been added to the specified object. Thus if an attribute were added to an object (but not a struct or enum), capable of storing key-value pairs, those pairs could be accessed via extension methods, hiding the storage mechanism from calling code. This is not quite as clean as extension properties would be, because of the unavoidable method pcall syntax, but is still useful in certain programming scenarios.

Since the object storing the data must inherit from System.Attribute, and it is unknown in advance what type of data will need to be stored, a straightforward solution is to create a class that both inherits from System.Attribute and implements IDictionary. Easy-to-use extension methods can then be made to wrap the use of this class, simplifying further the storage and retrieval of extension data.

Following is code for one such implementation:

```
/// <summary>
/// A System.Attribute which is also an IDictionary, useful for adding extension data to 
/// individual objects, no matter the type
/// </summary>
public class ExtensionDataAttribute : System.Attribute, IDictionary<string, object>
{
    // The dictionary wrapped by this collection, which cannot extend by System.Attribute and Dictionary at once
    private IDictionary<string, object> data = new Dictionary<string, object>();

    /// <summary>
    /// Adds this collection of extension data to the specified object; should be called only once
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="o">The object to which to add this collection of extension data</param>
    public void AddTo(object o) {
        System.ComponentModel.TypeDescriptor.AddAttributes(o, this);
    }

    // Following are encapsulated calls to the wrapped dictionary, which should need no explanation; 
    // after accessing an ExtensionDataAttribute instance, simply use it as an IDictionary<string, object>

    public void Add(string key, object value)
    {
        data.Add(key, value);
    }

    public bool ContainsKey(string key)
    {
        return data.ContainsKey(key);
    }

    public ICollection<string> Keys
    {
        get { return data.Keys; }
    }

    public bool Remove(string key)
    {
        return data.Remove(key);
    }

    public bool TryGetValue(string key, out object value)
    {
        return data.TryGetValue(key, out value);
    }

    public ICollection<object> Values
    {
        get { return data.Values; }
    }

    public object this[string key]
    {
        get
        {
            return data[key];
        }
        set
        {
            data[key] = value;
        }
    }

    public void Add(KeyValuePair<string, object> item)
    {
        data.Add(item);
    }

    public void Clear()
    {
        data.Clear();
    }

    public bool Contains(KeyValuePair<string, object> item)
    {
        return data.Contains(item);
    }

    public void CopyTo(KeyValuePair<string, object>[] array, int arrayIndex)
    {
        data.CopyTo(array, arrayIndex);
    }

    public int Count
    {
        get { return data.Count; }
    }

    public bool IsReadOnly
    {
        get { return data.IsReadOnly; }
    }

    public bool Remove(KeyValuePair<string, object> item)
    {
        return data.Remove(item);
    }

    public IEnumerator<KeyValuePair<string, object>> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return data.GetEnumerator();
    }

    System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return data.GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

... and some generic extension methods to wrap it up a bit further:

```
/// <summary>
/// Extension methods for setting and getting extension data for individual objects, no matter the type
/// </summary>
public static class ExtensionDataAttributeExtensions {

    public static void SetExtensionDataAttributeValue(this object o, string name, object value)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(name)) throw new ArgumentException("Invalid name");

        foreach (Attribute a in System.ComponentModel.TypeDescriptor.GetAttributes(o))
            if (a is ExtensionDataAttribute)
            {
                ((ExtensionDataAttribute)a)[name] = value;
                return;
            }

        ExtensionDataAttribute extensionData = new ExtensionDataAttribute();
        extensionData[name] = value;
        extensionData.AddTo(o);
    }

    public static T GetExtensionDataAttributeValue<T>(this object o, string name)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(name)) throw new ArgumentException("Invalid name");

        foreach (Attribute a in System.ComponentModel.TypeDescriptor.GetAttributes(o))
            if (a is ExtensionDataAttribute)
                return (T)((ExtensionDataAttribute)a)[name];

        return default(T);
    }

    public static object GetExtensionDataAttributeValue(this object o, string name)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(name)) throw new ArgumentException("Invalid name");

        foreach (Attribute a in System.ComponentModel.TypeDescriptor.GetAttributes(o))
            if (a is ExtensionDataAttribute)
                return ((ExtensionDataAttribute)a)[name];

        return null;
    }

    public static void RemoveExtensionDataAttributeValue(this object o, string name) {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(name)) throw new ArgumentException("Invalid name");
        foreach (Attribute a in System.ComponentModel.TypeDescriptor.GetAttributes(o))
            if (a is ExtensionDataAttribute)
                ((ExtensionDataAttribute)a).Remove(name);
    }

}
```

... and, finally, two examples of custom extension methods to use this idea in real-world code. One uses the ExtensionDataAttribute class directly (and is thus a little more nuts-and-bolts), the other uses the generic extension methods provided above:

```
/// <summary>
/// Extension methods showing samples of using the ExtensionDataAttribute class directly, for use 
/// in situations where it is undesirable to include the extension methods provided with that class
/// </summary>
public static class ExtensionMethodsExample1 {

    /// <summary>
    /// Adds a description to the specified string object
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="s">The string to describe</param>
    /// <param name="description">The description to set</param>
    public static void SetDescription(this string s, string description) {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(description))
            description = "";

        foreach (Attribute a in System.ComponentModel.TypeDescriptor.GetAttributes(s))
            if (a is ExtensionDataAttribute) {
                ((ExtensionDataAttribute)a)["Description"] = description;
                return;
            }

        ExtensionDataAttribute extensionData = new ExtensionDataAttribute();
        extensionData["Description"] = description;
        extensionData.AddTo(s);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the description for the specified string, if it has one; 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="s"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static string GetDescription(this string s) {
        foreach (Attribute a in System.ComponentModel.TypeDescriptor.GetAttributes(s))
            if (a is ExtensionDataAttribute) {
                ExtensionDataAttribute eda = (ExtensionDataAttribute)a;
                if (eda.ContainsKey("Description"))
                    return eda["Description"].ToString();
                else
                    return "";
            }
        return "";
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Extension methods encapsulating calls to extension methods provided with the ExtensionDataAttribute 
/// class, demonstrating increased ease of implementing one's own extension data
/// </summary>
public static class ExtensionMethodsExample2 {
    public static string GetDescription(this string s)
    {
        return s.GetExtensionDataAttributeValue<string>("Description");
    }

    public static void SetDescription(this string s, string description)
    {
        s.SetExtensionDataAttributeValue("Description", description);
    }
}
```

I hope that these ideas have been useful. One doesn't always have the luxury of extending a class, and in some situations it may make the design of extension methods cleaner if one does not have to assemble and pass in extra information with each method call, on an object which may not have been created in the developer's codebase at all.

Comment: Very clever - thankfully I can't say I've *needed* this (it's easier to avoid a need if starting the with assumption that it's not possible), but clever anyway. I would imagine the object reachability graph is still taken care of an the additional data does not start a "memory leak"?

Comment: @user2246674: Thank you! I was happy when I figured it out. Your question's a good one. I'm assuming the answer is "yes", since System.Attribute is freely extensible, because by design it can be attached to individual objects as well as types, and because many attributes have data values attached to them which are unknown at compile time, plus can be mutable. I guess your question is the same as: are System.Attribute instances interned in some way? I can't find any reference on this but will test...

Answer (score 0):

Sure there is. All you need is a Dictionary that is accessible to whoever interacts with the data. Whenever you need the data you call TheDataStore[theObject] and get back the value object containing whatever properties you desire.

At the abstract level, such a property store is how [attached properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms749011.aspx) work in WPF.

Comment: Yes, one can use external collections. I have edited the question to make it more clear. The idea is whether or not one can attach data to individual objects, without using inheritance, in a fairly clean way. The method I've shown is a sort of Rube Goldberg approach in that it uses attributes in a way for which they weren't intended, but it seems to work well enough and can result in clean calling code, which is saved from having to have knowledge of external data structures and the like.

Comment: Since you mentioned extension methods, you could access static collections inside them. Basically having extension methods implement getters/setters. Be wary that you may want to look into the topic of weak references as static collections of standard references  will preventi stuff from being garbage collected.

Comment: Your comments and those below have led to what I feel is the best approach... going to edit my previous answer.  See if you like it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I was thinking something like:

```
static class Ext
{
  static readonly Dictionary<YourType, int> fooValues = new Dictionary<YourType, int>();

  public static int GetFoo(this YourType yt)
  {
    int value;
    fooValues.TryGetValue(yt, out value);
    return value;
  }
  public static void SetFoo(this YourType yt, int value)
  {
    fooValues[yt] = value;
  }
}
```

This is just a sketch, of course. If `YourType` (or any class derived from it) overrides `Equals` and `GetHashCode` you might want to give a custom equality comparer to the `fooValues` data store. The `Dictionary<,>` is not thread-safe, so if parallelism is needed use another collection or use locks.

It's probably a problem that each instance "extended" like this will never be garbage collected. You could try to use weak references instead, somehow. See comment by svick below.

Comment: I think the biggest issue with this is that it leaks memory, whenever you set something, the value will be stored forever, even after the parent would normally be GCed (unless you explicitly unset it). [`ConditionalWeakTable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287757.aspx) could help with that.

Comment: Yes, I came to think of that as well.

Comment: @svick I didn't know that class, `ConditionalWeakTable<,>`. It is exactly what we need here! We would need to put our `int` into a container `class MutableInt32 { public int Value; }`, it seems. Then we could use `ConditionalWeakTable<YourType, MutableInt32>`.

Comment: Neither did I! I am going to play with ConditionalWeakTable a little and see what I can come up with.

Comment: @svick: I think that's just what the doctor ordered.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen: I think we've hit it on the head. Thanks to you and svick and Tormod in particular.