# Find "Collection" from subobject

Tags: c#, list

Is there a method to understand if a generic C# Object is part of a collection? And is there a way to retrieve said collection?

I know an Object is not aware of being part of another (no references stored anywhere about parents) but maybe one could use reflection on generic collections.

Comment: do you mean that you don't know which collection it might be part of? Or would you have a particular collection in mind and simply want to find out if the object is contained within it?

Comment: You can't get a parent (collection) from an item in the collection unless a property exists in the child.  In most cases you need to enumerate through the collection to find children with properties using a search.

Comment: @jdweng: I supposed that as well...storing a new prop seems the best way to achieve such result.

Comment: @sonik let me know if my answer fits your problem ..

Answer (score 0):

To answer original question : no, you're not supposed to be able to find parent collection of an object, and reflection probably won't help.

But you may be able to achieve what you need by modifying behavior of ICollection.Add() by using extension methods and storing in each added objects a reference to their common container.

Putting additional data in objects seems to be achievable, as it is stated here :
[How can additional data be associated with existing objects using extension methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17264479/how-can-additional-data-be-associated-with-existing-objects-using-extension-meth)

There may be other solutions to achieve what you need, but on my self I'd go with something like that.